# If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and $(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)=16$, then $a+b+c=3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real number such that 
>   $$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)=16$$
>   then $a+b+c=3$

I think this is trivial but I don't know how to prove this fact.

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: it must be wrong, let b=1, c=1, it is clear that the solution for a is not 1

Comment: Do you mean $(1+a+b+c)(1+1/a+1/b+1/c)=16$?

Comment: @MathLover: I edit your question. I remove the plus sign in the middle. Because if it were then this result is wrong.If you feel I'm missing something, kindly go ahead  and edit again!

Comment: You have edited right ...Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is already appeared on this site. Hold on ....I mention that link!

Comment: also see this quora link (https://www.quora.com/Suppose-1+a+b+c-1+1-a+1-b+1-c-16-whats-the-value-of-a+b+c-where-a-b-c-are-positive-real-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Using AM HM [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) for non-negative numbers,

$$\dfrac{\sum_{r=1}^na_r}n\ge\dfrac n{\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac1{a_r}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the AM-HM inequality of $1, a, b, c$.

So $$\frac{1 + a + b + c}{4} \geq \frac{4}{1 + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}}$$

This gives $$(1 + a + b + c)\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\bigg) \geq 16$$.

The equality becomes an equation only when all four elements are equal.

i.e. $1=a=b=c$. So $a + b + c = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality you can even show that $a=b=c=1$:
$$(1+a+b+c)\left(1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right) = \left(1^2 + \sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2 \right)\left(1^2 + \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2 \right)$$ $$\stackrel{C.-S.}{\geq}(1+1+1+1)^2 = 16$$
**Equality** holds for $(1\: \sqrt{a} \: \sqrt{b} \: \sqrt{c})^T = \lambda \cdot \left( 1\: \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \: \: \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} \: \: \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^T \Rightarrow a=b=c = 1$